# IncompatibleClassChangeError running Cucumber tests in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

When I run a cucumber test feature in IntelliJ, all it shows is an IncompatibleClassChangeError with stack trace:

```
Testing started at 12:55 ...
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface cucumber.api.TestCase, but class was expected
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.handleTestCaseStarted(CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.access$000(CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.java:17)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter$1.receive(CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter$1.receive(CucumberJvm2SMFormatter.java:30)
    at cucumber.runner.EventBus.send(EventBus.java:28)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:37)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runFeature(Runtime.java:120)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:106)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

This is `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-181.5087.20`, with `Cucumber for Java version 181.5087.20`

Comment: Could you specify IDE version? Do you have a sample case to check?

Comment: @Andrey added the version numbers

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to track: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192612

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is solved in the latest version.

You can recreate the configuration (so it will be updated automatically), or you can replace the program arguments with

```
--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter
```

An older version of the plugin was not compatible with cucumber java version 3 and higher. If you are stuck with that one you can update your build.gradle to specify version 2 explicitly:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:2.+'
}
```

Comment: Also, if included, update:
 testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:2.+'

Answer (score 11):

As explained in [issue #1392](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1392)

> This is caused by IDEA's CucumberJvm2SMFormatter. It being the
>   formatter for Cucumber2, runs into a breaking change in Cucumber 3.

The simplest workaround is removing `--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm2SMFormatter` from program arguments in the run configuration.

Comment: Is it possible to remove that plugin from run defaults? When I try to edit default cucumber java run then "Program arguments" field is empty.